# Druid - Prevent new partition from getting created on each CSV ingestion

Tags: druid

I have ingestion spec

```
        "rollup": false,
        "segmentGranularity" : "day",
        "queryGranularity" : {
            "type": "duration",
            "duration": 60000
        }
      }
    },
    "ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "index",
      "inputSource" : {
        "type" : "local"
       },
       "inputFormat": {
         "type": "csv"
       },
       "appendToExisting": true
    }
```

Every time I call the API to ingest, it's creating new partition
[image]
Is there a way to prevent creating new partition on each ingestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segments are immutable, so you can't avoid this on ingestion.  (Druid won't write into an existing segment.). You could compact the segments later, though, eg see https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-compaction.html .  In newer versions, there's also autocompaction that you can enable.  Eg, see https://docs.imply.io/3.0/on-prem/manage-data/compaction .